# Update Microsoft SQL Server value without unique key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on creating a front end for a role access management program. I need to figure out how to update a `userName` that does not have a unique value. Also in the table it has a `loweredUserName` column.

Here is my SQL statement:

```
UPDATE mssql_Users
SET UserName = @UserName,
    LoweredUserName = LOWER(@UserName)
WHERE UserName = @UserName
```

So basically if there are multiple versions of the user name `'testUser'`  I want to replace every instance of `'testUser'` with the new name of say `'userTest'` without having any other unique id

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have posted?

Comment: Why do you even *need* the `LoweredUserName` column? It's just data repetition and doesn't adds anything. Also, why isn't the `UserName` column unique? Repeated usernames doesn't seem OK to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need two variables:

```
DECLARE @oldUserName varchar(200) = 'Old'
DECLARE @newUserName varchar(200) = 'New'

UPDATE mssql_Users
SET UserName = @newUserName,
    LoweredUserName = LOWER(@newUserName)
WHERE UserName = @oldUserName
```